# Cannot resolve symbol '@+id/editName

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I wrote a code but I have only one red line in xml file and one in the java file: Cannot resolve symbol '@+id/editName

Here the xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_register"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.loginproject.RegisterActivity">

    <TextView
        android:text="SQLite User Registration"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:hint="Enter Name"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/editName"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:hint="Enter Email"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editName"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/editEmail"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:hint="Enter Password"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editEmail"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/editPassword"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/buttonRegister"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editPassword"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Register From here "/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and here the RegisterActivity.java with only the part with editName:

```
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.text.TextUtils;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    ...
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

            Register = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonRegister);

            Email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editEmail);
            Password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editPassword);
            Name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editName);
...
```

I have the error only for editName inside both files and not for editPassword or editEmail.

When I try to run the app it stops working on the virtual device, but it shows no error when I debug that, so I cannot understand where's the problem.

Could I forgot to do something?

Comment: android:inputType="textEmailAddress" seems wrong, rest ok; name your variables with lowerCamelCase; build it clean with gradle and see what happens

Comment: perfect, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any problem with .java file just make the below change in your .xml file.

```
 <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:hint="Enter Name"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/editName"
        android:gravity="center"/>
```

Just remove the

```
android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
```

so your code will be like this

```
 <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter Name"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/editName"
        android:gravity="center"/>
```